# Gitlab Style Network Graphs on Github

Tags: github, gitlab

One of the things i really liked on Gitlab was their network graphs[image: gitlab network graph]

Is there a way to get a similar look/feel in Github? [image: github network graph]

I find the gitlab version much easier to work with

Answer (score 5):

We've just moved our client work from a self-hosted GitLab instance to private GitHub repositories and I feel the same pain - I live on the GitLab network graph page!

So I've gone ahead and got it working for any local repository. That's not quite GitHub of course, but you can locally clone any GitHub project to use it.

The code and instructions are at https://github.com/chromatixau/gitlab-network-graph. It's not perfect yet - there are issues with getting the right 'space' allocation on the graph for some merge strategies, but it works for most simpler situations. I'm continuing to work on it.

The steps were basically to copy the [network related frontend JS files](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/v9.3.4/app/assets/javascripts/network) from the MIT-licensed GitLab CE repository, build a small webpack config based on GitLab's, and then put together some scripts to create the JSON that GitLab builds the graph from (I've used a shell script to basically run git log and format it as JSON, and then a Node.js script to further massage that JSON).

Comment: Hey Tim, your link to the github repo is 404-ing, it seems like your github org has removed the repo. Has it moved somewhere else?

Comment: @Splatmistro Sorry about that! Should be fixed now. I privatised the repo in a recent review - forgot I posted it here :)

Comment: Thanks, it looks awesome!